# What is this strange expression in GCC/Clang?

Tags: c++, c, gcc-statement-expression

I have recently noticed an strange valid **C/C++** expression in **GCC/Clang** which I have never seen before. Here is the example in **C++**, but similar expression works in **C** too:

```
int main(){
    int z = 5;
    auto x = ({z > 3 ? 3 : 2;}); // <-- expression
    std::cout << x;
}
```

What it does is somehow obvious, but I like to know what it is called. Since it does not worth in **MSVC**, I guess it is a non-standard extension. But is there anything that works for **MSVC** too? especially in **C**?

Comment: It's a GCC extension: [Statement Exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). It seems an unnecessary usage of it in this case. (It could have been written as `auto x = (z > 3 ? 3 : 2);` without any nasty extensions.)

Comment: What @IanAbbott said. With `-Wpendantic` I get a warning: `warning: ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @IanAbbott yea, I know it is unnecessary, I just wanted to write a sample code with it. I saw its usage in `max()` macro, but not in that page :D

Comment: It is mostly used in macros defined with parameters when the programmer wishes to avoid the parameters being expanded more than once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of ({ ... }) brackets in macros to swallow the semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409694/use-of-brackets-in-macros-to-swallow-the-semicolon)

Comment: [In what versions of C is a block inside parenthesis used to return a value valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1635549/995714), [Use of ({ … }) brackets in macros to swallow the semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5409694/995714)

Comment: For `max()` it can be used with another GCC extension `typeof` as shown in [Typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html). In the `max(a,b)` macro example given there, the statement expr and typeof extensions are used to define local variables with the same types as the parameters and initialized to the values of the parameters. That way, the parameters are only expanded once, and the local variables are accessed more than once to determine the maximum value.

Comment: I learned something new about this .. I thought it was named a tenary operation :)

Comment: C++ has a portable way to include statements in expression contexts; an immediately-evaluated lambda: `auto z = []{ if (z>3) return 3; return 2; }()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [statement expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), used in GCC. Your expression `({z > 3 ? 3 : 2;})` can be translated to

```
if (z > 3) {x = 3;} else {x = 2;}
```

From documentation:

> A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an
> expression in GNU C. This allows you to use loops, switches, and local
> variables within an expression.

In other word, it provides the ability to put a compound statement in an expression position.

Related post :

- [Emulating GCC Statement Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102415/emulating-gcc-statement-expressions)
- [Use of ({ ... }) brackets in macros to swallow the semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409694/use-of-brackets-in-macros-to-swallow-the-semicolon)

Comment: But given that `z > 3 ? 3 : 2` is a valid expression, the _statement expression_ syntax is not necessary here I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is called conditional operator . Return will be depend on condition either condition is true or false.

But in this case:
auto x = ({z > 3 ? 3 : 2;}); // <-- expression

if Z is greater than 3 returns 3 otherwise 2.

Basic syntax : Expression1? expression2: expression3;

Comment: The _"strange"_ thing here is not the ternary `?:` operator, but the `{...}` braces and the semi-colon.