# Trying to write a macro, but not sure what's wrong

Tags: macros

I've been playing around with macros. I saw an interesting post where I can structure my macro in a function like structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163365/how-do-i-make-a-c-macro-behave-like-a-function). I've tried to implement one and here is what I currently have.

```
#define Max(X,Y) \
do { \
     auto var1 = x; \
     auto var2 = y;  \
     var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2; \
} while (0)
```

and in my main function

```
void main()
{
   int result = Max(10, 5)
}
```

but I'm getting all these errors,

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'do'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Not sure what I did wrong. I just copied the code from the hyperlink above and just modified the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why bother with macros? Just stuff it in a function and let the compiler inline it.

Comment: Macros are not functions, nor lambdas as you're apparently using them...

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I removed the c++ tag, but I just wanted to play around and learn how macro can be used.

Comment: Oh and doing something like `result = Max(++i, x)` will make debugging really really fun.

Comment: @KemyLand So is the code that I written, just wrong?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I am aware that ++i will cause a bug since macro just replaces texts, I am not using this anywhere. I just want to play around with macros

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the macro.  The problem is that, unlike a lot of other languages, C++ loop control blocks do not have a return value.  This means you can't assign something to the result of a loop because there is no such result.

Comment: @ChrisHayden I dont follow, is the auto var1 and auto var2 causing the errors?

Comment: do { } while() doesn't return anything. And it has no value. You cannot assign it to variable.

Comment: You're aware that macros are text replacement. Then you should see that the fault lies in the use. `int result = do {...} while (0);` is not valid.

Comment: @chris OH. I see. Thanks, I was totally missing that part.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That's the point of assigning the parameters to local variables, so you don't get multiple side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what the macro expands into:

```
int result = do {
     auto var1 = x;
     auto var2 = y;
     var1 > var2 ? var1 : var2;
} while (0);
```

That's not valid C++ because loops don't have return values in C++.

Oh, and I actually did notice a small problem with the macro.  The parameter names are capitalized (X, Y) but used as lower-case (x, y).  That will not work as expected.  You have to use the same name in the macro body as you used for the macro parameters.